# How to instantiate different subclass on the basis of configuration file in a better way?

Tags: python, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a base class and multiple sub classes inheriting from it. I need to instantiate correct subclass on the basis of configuration file provided. Now, one way to do this is to use if,else statement and check the configuration file to instantiate subclass but it seems bad programming code. Also, later if I add more subclasses, the if-else chain will grow really long. Can someone suggest a better way to do this?

I have a template code where instead of configuration file I am taking a command line argument to do the same thing.

```
class Shape(object):
    pass

class Rectangle(Shape):
    pass

class Circle(Shape):
    pass

class Polygon(Shape):
    pass

import argparse
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--shape', help='Provide the shape')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.shape == 'circle':
        shape = Circle()
        print(shape.__class__.__name__)
    elif args.shape == 'rectangle':
        shape = Rectangle()
        print(shape.__class__.__name__)
    elif args.shape == 'polygon':
        shape = Polygon()
        print(shape.__class__.__name__)
    else:
        raise Exception("Shape not defined")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put all your class in a dictionary object like that

```
my_shapes = { "rectangle" : Rectangle, "circle": Circle, "polygon": Polygon }
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.shape in my_shapes:
    shape = my_shapes[args.shape]() #Here you will do the same thing that the if else 
else:
    raise Exception("Shape not defined")
```

Comment: I was going to comment that you hadn't accounted for `"Shape not defined"`, but then I realised that `my_shapes[args.shape]` will throw an exception anyway.